# Does it make sense for a PUT REST API method to accept extraneous data?

Tags: api, rest, httprequest, put

My JavaScript application uses a RESTful API which I am developing.

When editing and saving a record via my UI, I do a PUT against /widget/:id, passing a complete data object, and then the entire record is replaced and returned. Typical PUT method.

However, my UI's data models sometimes contain extra data items outside the scope of a widget; for instance, the data model may contain

- id
- name
- category_id
- price
- category  <--- EXTRA DATA

  - id
  - name

As you can see, "category" is extra data. If I serialize my data model (e.g., model.toJSON()), then *category and its attributes will be included in the serialization*.

**So, my question is:** from a theoretical REST standpoint, is it okay to send *all* of the data above to the PUT API method and expect the method to strip out extraneous data keys prior to saving? Or, should the client always remove extra data prior to making the PUT request?

Answer (score 1):

By sending a `PUT` request to an URI, the client tells the server how he wants the server state of this resource to be. The server decides how and if server state is chaged. He  has two basic options.

1. Check that the request body conforms to what the server `Accepts`. If he won't just accept any `application/json` but a `application/vnd.your.content.type+json`, he will reject JSON that has `category` which probably is not valid for this type.
2. Accept the request and silently discard the extra `category`.

Option 2 is OK :)